# What is the best way sort 2-D list and transform it to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a 2-D `[2xn]` array with keys in the first column (which repeat) and values in the second. I need to make a dictionary, where keys are unique, and there values are collected from the values.

What is the smartest way to do it? Should I first preprocess (sort keys-values in groups or something) or should I put a `set(keys)` to dictionary keys and then operate with values there? Or should I put `keys` and `values` lists in a dictionary and "squeeze" it somehow?

Input:

```
[
[Isis, 3],
[Isis, 4],
[Al-Qaeda, 2],
[Isis, 2]
]
```

Desired output:

```
{'Isis':[3,4,2], 'Al-Qaeda':[2]}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of potential input and desired output? What have you tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in input:
    output[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = {}
for i in input:
    key = i[0]
    value = i[1]
    if not key in output:
        output[key] = []
    output[key].append(value)
```

Comment: Sorry for all the edits.  I posted without first testing and found some typos

Comment: sir, i think, the 5th  line is unnecessery

Comment: @VladislavLadenkov The if statement?  If we don't include that, we put a new list in output[key] every time we go to 'add' a value!

Comment: @VladislavLadenkov It's worth mentioning.  The lines key = i[0] and value = i[1] are completely unnecessary.  I just included them for clarity.

Comment: @ Oh yee, but cant we just somehow determine the values with default empty lists, so we could just use the `append` method?

Comment: @VladislavLadenkov That's exactly what the above answer does (which is why I upvoted it!)